# Simplify java if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, verbosity

Can I simplify this java if construct? It seems too verbose to me, I'd like to have it shorter.

A is persistent Object, which will be null if it's context is accessed first time. Than A is instatniated and given content, and if this fails, some backup content is given to A.

```
if (A == null) {
    A = staticGetMethod();
    if (A == null) A = new BackupAContent() { ... };
}
```

Comment: I find it perfectly readable, and don't find it verbose at all. Don't change anything.

Comment: None of those the answer then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your building logic in factory method

```
if (objA == null) {
    objA = getAInstance();

}
```

encapsulate the code suggested by Charles into a method to implement [Factory_method_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: I don't understand, can you decribe the getAInstance() method?

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Or you could simply remove the nesting as it will still behave the same way.

```
if (A == null) {
    A = staticGetMethod();
}
if (A == null) {
    new BackupAContent() { ... };
}
```

---

Should work:

```
if (A == null && (A = staticGetMethod()) == null) {
    new BackupAContent() { ... };
}
```

Comment: This would do something different then the original construct, It would call staticMethod even if the A != null.

Comment: And is at least in my opinion much more ungainly than the original and wrong which shows why this is such a bad idea :)

Comment: Would work, but it's horrible code -- please don't put assignments in the middle of statements like that!

Comment: I would arguable this is less readable and worst (stylistically) than the original

Comment: Oh, I agree, but he wanted to simplify it and that's the only way I could think of without refactoring... which admittedly is probably the answer.

Comment: What if `A != null` and `(A = staticGetMethod()) == null`? Your if statement will be `true` while the OP's if statement will be `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator instead of the `if` statements:

```
a = a ? a : staticGetMethod();
a = a ? a : new BackupAContent();
```

That said, I'd stick with what you've got, to be honest -- except that I would add a block for the second conditional rather than putting the statement inline with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Charles Goodwin's code with a slight change:

```
if (A == null && (A = staticGetMethod()) == null) {
new BackupAContent() { ... };
}
```

I used an AND instead of an OR

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
if(A == null)
{
    if((A = staticGetMethod()) == null) A = new BackupAContent() { ... };
}
```